# Why did God the Father choose suffering for Christ and not the lucrative reigning power of an emperor of this world?

Tags: will-of-god, suffering

My witness to suffering can be elaborated by the following poem written by me. I am attaching this poem because I believe this poem a witness to my long journey with my cross assures me that I am following Christ's wishes but leaves a question unanswered. I have asked that small question at the end of the poem. I hope somebody here can answer that and help me understand God the Father well from a Catholic perspective.

> Adoration at Golgotha
>
> By mvr950
>
> Adoration began.
>
> Adoree before the adored.
>
> Before the exposed monstrance.
>
> People cry out to Heaven.
>
> For a drop of Holy Water.
>
> The night deludes them.
>
> To take the route to Satan’s
>
> quiver and crescendo.
>
> I deny myself to take that path.
>
> I reject to take that false pathos.
>
> Because I have the cross of Christ
>
> living within me.
>
> I have taken up a fraction of an
>
> infinitesimally small fraction
>
> of His suffering.
>
> He has given me tiniest but
>
> impossible to carry a cross.
>
> I prostrate before Him.
>
> Genuflect before Him.
>
> Kneel down on the pew
>
> so a crowbar cannot lift me up.
>
> I lay before Him.
>
> I kiss His bloody feet at Golgotha
>
> as I am crucified along with Him.
>
> The rebuke, the mockery, the rebuttal,
>
> the screams, the cries, the smirks
>
> all are pointed at Him and me.
>
> I gave up my last drop of dignity
>
> only for Christ.
>
> Only for God the son.
>
> Only for the son of man.
>
> In Him, I live.
>
> He requested me to carry the cross.
>
> And I give my all
>
> only for Him.
>
> I know, in Him I will find
>
> the truth, life, and the light.
>
> I believe God will separate
>
> the harvest from the chaffs.
>
> Cause He is the Just God.
>
> Our lust for power
>
> will find the last meaning
>
> at the end of the epitaph
>
> engraved on the tombstone.
>
> Our sins of the flesh
>
> will be crushed by the holy stature of God.
>
> And we will hear those sweet condescending words
>
> This is the Domus Dei Omnipotentis. Come and join us.

Now God chose Christ to die on the cross. And give suffering meaning. Now my question is Can't God the Father choose Christ to come in reigning power as an emperor of the world to become a savior? Why did God the Father choose suffering for Christ instead?

It must be God the Father. Because Jesus at Gethsemani said, "Abba, Father if it were possible, take this chalice away from me. But not what I will what thou wilt." And on the Cross Jesus said, "Eli Eli Lama Sabachthani". "My God, My God why have you forsaken me?"

Comment: If Christ didn't die, what is your proposed solution for sin? I think you need to explain that, or else the question seems very unmotivated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Why did God the Father choose suffering for Christ and not the lucrative reigning power of emperor of this world?*

**ANSWER**

The biblical answer is, Jesus said His Kingdom is not on this world.

> “[33] *Then Pilate entered into the judgment hall again, and called Jesus, and said unto him, Art thou the King of the Jews? [*34] **Jesus answered him, Sayest thou this thing of thyself, or did others tell it thee of me?** [35] *Pilate answered, Am I a Jew? Thine own nation and the chief priests have delivered thee unto me: what hast thou done?* [36] **Jesus answered, My kingdom is not of this world: if my kingdom were of this world, then would my servants fight, that I should not be delivered to the Jews: but now is my kingdom not from hence.”***(John18:33-36)

*How about the suffering of Christ?*

**God in eternity desires to share His goodness and glory to mankind.** But there's one big problem with God desire. What is the problem with desiring a thing that is so precious that one is willing to give his all just to acquire that desire?

How can this problem be solve? Only one way is possible for all mankind to enter God's Kingdom. God has to offer His Divine Mercy.

In the words of St.Faustina;

> **"Mercy is the flower of love, in love it is conceived and in mercy it is revealed."**

Jesus as the Christ, is the Divine Mercy made flesh, and for Him to become flesh, God in eternity had dreamed of a Woman who will bear His only begotten Son.

> "Mary is God's dreamed." (Blessed Ab.Fulton Sheen)

Since God dreamed to possessed the chosen Woman, and "desire" Her to be the Theotokos. God knew being Omnipotent that it is only possible by offering a "sacrifice", and there's is no acceptable sacrifice to God other than His only begotten Son.

> "For God so loved the world that he gave his one and only Son, that whoever believes in him shall not perish but have eternal life." (John3:16)

The First Act of God in eternity is to offer His Divine Mercy, and the first recipient of God's Divine Mercy is the chosen Woman. God in eternity had given the chosen Woman all the graces needed for Her to become the "Heart of Salvation of all mankind".

The answer is, *"when one desire a precious thing it involves a sacrifice"*. God in eternity saw that His desire for a finite created being to enter His Kingdom is impossible for man. There's is only one way for mankind to enter God's Kingdom, there's no other way. The finite man cannot devise his own way to enter God's Kingdom.

What is the only way for a finite man to enter God's Kingdom? **It is called the *"Way of the Cross".*** The *"Way of the Cross"* entails a sacrifice or a suffering. God is the Alpha and Omega, He had seen the beginning and the end of His creation, and His Divine Plan was already written in eternity before the creation time begin.

So,, the answer is God's Kingdom is not of this world, and it entails suffering because that is the only way for man to enter God's Kingdom. ***"The Way of the Cross"*** involves a sacrifice in the form of sufferings as the means most pleasing to God to atone for the sins of mankind.

*Is the "Way of the Cross" written in the bible?* Yes! it is written in Genesis1:1 and it it's the ***"hidden Wisdom"*** of God that was concealed to all the angels esp. the "fallen angels". Genesis1:1 in Hebrew word is "Bereshit", and the hidden mystery or wisdom behind that word can only be known by understanding it's tetragrammaton meaning.

What is the Hebrew tetragrammaton meaning of the word "Bereshit" written in Genesis1:1?

***Bereshit*** tetragammaton essence when translated is; ***"The Son of the Almighty God willingly offered His life on the Cross to pour out His "merciful graces or Divine Mercy" to save all mankind".***

But since, God is so merciful; He gave us an image which Jesus had shown to Sis. Lucia in 1929 to help us depict the Divine Plan of God for the Salvation of Mankind. The image below is the last vision of Sis. Lucia and it is perfect image of the Hebrew word ***"Bereshit"*** written in Genesis1:1)

[image]

*In closing, is there a person who knew this Divine Plan of God?* Yes! there is one person or spirit who knew the Divine Plan of God because She witness God's creation, She is called the Spirit of Wisdom in Proverbs8:22. The Spirit of Wisdom is the *"anointing"* received by Jesus as the ***"Christ or Anointed One"*** to become the Redeemer, and it is also the *"anointing"* received the ***"chosen Woman"*** to become the Co-redemptrix. If we possessed the Spirit of Wisdom like King Solomon did, then we will know why Jesus Kingship is not like an emperor or an earthly King and why God allowed Him to suffer by embracing the Way of the Cross.

Answer (score 1):

Jesus told us the answer when explained three things:

1. What is God's chief motivation?
2. What is the greatest expression of that motivation?
3. Who are the disciples?

First, God's chief motivation is love:

> 36 “Teacher, which is the greatest commandment in the Law?”
>
> 37 Jesus replied: “‘Love the Lord your God with all your heart and
>   with all your soul and with all your mind.’[c] 38 This is the first
>   and greatest commandment. (Matthew 22:36-37)

Second, the greatest expression of love is to lay your life down for your friends:

> 9 “As the Father has loved me, so have I loved you. Now remain in my
>   love. 10 If you keep my commands, you will remain in my love, just as
>   I have kept my Father’s commands and remain in his love. 11 I have
>   told you this so that my joy may be in you and that your joy may be
>   complete. 12 My command is this: Love each other as I have loved you.
>   13 **Greater love has no one than this: to lay down one’s life for
>   one’s friends.** (John 15:9-13)

Third, Jesus declares the disciples are his friends:

> 14 **You are my friends** if you do what I command. 15 I no longer
>   call you servants, because a servant does not know his master’s
>   business. **Instead, I have called you friends**, for everything that
>   I learned from my Father I have made known to you. 16 You did not
>   choose me, but I chose you and appointed you so that you might go and
>   bear fruit—fruit that will last—and so that whatever you ask in my
>   name the Father will give you. 17 This is my command: Love each other.
>   (John 15:14-17)

We know of soldiers, firemen, parents, and police who have laid down their life for people they loved. Are they greater than God? No! Thus if God values love and is the greatest lover in the universe and that love requires giving your life for those you love and you have picked people to call friends, you must do as Jesus did.

As for the false choice, Jesus *will* return to reign as emperor of the world. However, when he does, the time for mercy will have passed; he will come to judge the living and the dead. It is for the sake of sinners who need time to repent that Jesus delays his return, so that as many may be saved as possible.

However, since you are a poet, a fitting response is found in one of God's greatest poems, Job. As you read this, having heard all the things that Leviathan will NOT do for you, understand that the point of this speech is to declare what God WILL do for you!

```
41 “Can you pull in Leviathan with a fishhook
    or tie down its tongue with a rope?
2 Can you put a cord through its nose
    or pierce its jaw with a hook?
3 Will it keep begging you for mercy?
    Will it speak to you with gentle words?
4 Will it make an agreement with you
    for you to take it as your slave for life?
5 Can you make a pet of it like a bird
    or put it on a leash for the young women in your house?
6 Will traders barter for it?
    Will they divide it up among the merchants?
7 Can you fill its hide with harpoons
    or its head with fishing spears?
8 If you lay a hand on it,
    you will remember the struggle and never do it again!
9 Any hope of subduing it is false;
    the mere sight of it is overpowering.
10 No one is fierce enough to rouse it.
    Who then is able to stand against me?
11 Who has a claim against me that I must pay?
    Everything under heaven belongs to me.
```

Jesus was tied up, was pierced, does speak tenderly, does make a covenant to serve us, his garments were bartered away, and his side was thrust through with a spear. On the flip side, Leviathan represents the evil world system (and its head, Satan), an empire of force that dominates the World for evil. That is something God did not want for his Son. Leviathan will be destroyed, and its end is written of in Revelation 13. Jesus' empire will be different, because the master will be the servant of all.

Comment: "Can you pull in Leviathan with a fishhook or tie down its tongue with a rope?
Can you put a cord through its nose or pierce its jaw with a hook? Yes, the Leviathian can be tied up but not with a rope or a cord. We need a "great chain" as Revelation20:1 said. What is the "great chain"? It's a secret written in John19:27.

Answer (score 0):

*Can't God the Father choose Christ to come in reigning power as an emperor of the world to become a savior?*

Yes HE can and will when Jesus Christ's Return and Reign

> [Revelation 20:4] And I saw thrones, and they sat upon them, and judgment was given unto them: and I saw the souls of them that were beheaded for the witness of Jesus, and for the word of God, and which had not worshipped the beast, neither his image, neither had received his mark upon their foreheads, or in their hands; and they lived and reigned with Christ a thousand years.

*Why did God the Father choose suffering for Christ instead?*

For our own sake, Christ needed to suffer as a sacrifice for our sins so we could be forgiven

> [Hebrews 9:22] And almost all things are by the law purged with blood; and without 
>   shedding of blood is no remission.
>
> [Hebrews 9:28] So Christ, having been offered once to bear the sins of many, will appear a second time, not to deal with sin but to save those who are eagerly waiting for him.